# Are there really over 270 first posts today?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I came back today, at my usual time, to run through the review sections in the ServerFault SE.  Today I noted that over 270 first posts were indicated as being in the first posts queue.  I am generally up-to-date and have not found that many in a single day.  This is VERY unusual and seemingly too high for a single 24 hour period, especially with all the other reviewers around.

Was just wondering if this unusual activity was the result of some type of problem in the system?

Comment: They had [nearly 10K on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173894/189912).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it was the result of a problem - one that was fixed.

[A bug in the First Posts review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173886/189912) was causing questions from new users to not be added to the queue. The bug fix was rolled out earlier today.

The fix resulted in some [10,000 questions being added to the queue on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173894/189912).

Answer (score 2):

It was 343, actually.

And it happens when they change the algorithm, like with the late posts review queue back when they started the new system - they restricted it to a date range, waited for the queue to empty, and then expanded the date range.  In this case, they probably made the criteria for first posts/new users more permissive, which resulted in the new posts in the queue.